# WebView: is performFindPanelAction still not implemented?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview

I am trying to implement a Find Panel like in Safari or Mac Mail, but `performFindPanelAction` its not working for me. I found that while ago bugs were filed with Apple about it, but I don't know if that's still the case... If it's a still an empty method, how can I open a Find Panel with a webView?